# Create sequence of numbers, excluding certain numbers

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to create a sequence of 1:85, but excluding the numbers in seq(1,85,5). So like this:

```
2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 12 13 etc..
```

What would be an efficient way to do this in R?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `setdiff`:

```
setdiff(1:85,seq(1,85,5))
 [1]  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 12 ...
```

Comment: @edwardyanquen look at the output of `seq(1,85,5)`. The OP wants to exclude these numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know setdiff() before, it seems really useful.

Answer (score 6):

If the numbers you want to exclude can't be generalized, @HongOoi or @James answers are the way to go. But if they can be described by some mathematical test, `Filter` would be more efficient.

```
Filter(function(x) x %% 5 != 1, 1:85)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(1:85)[-seq(1, 85, 5)]
```

or is that too obvious/inefficient?

Comment: Not quite so obvious to me apparently.. Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I should probably mention that this trick only works if your initial sequence is of the form `1,2,3,...N`. It's removing elements based on their position in the sequence, not on their value. James' answer works regardless of what sequence you begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n <- 85
setdiff(1:n, c(1,85,5))
```

Comment: I recommend you provide additional information about the answer so the OP can understand the answer better. Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)